# Cells in excel showing a "0" value when I reference other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I get an excel sheet from another person (any person) and try to make changes or reference cells with formulas the results do not flow through and show my references as "0".  If I paste in the hard numbers my formulas work.  I have automatic calculation set.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use value(reference) maybe the reference is for a text cell or any format that cannot be calculated with your Formulas

Answer (score 1):

This is very common.  A formula like:

```
=Sheet1!B9
```

will return **0** whether **B9** is empty or contains a **0**

To make it show empty, use:

```
=IF(Sheet1!B9="","",Sheet1!B9)
```